# Extending CompletionPolicy to complete/commit per resource from MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

My problem is I don't understand the various spring batch contexts. The reference documentation explains how to pass data to future steps. But how do I pass data between the reader and writer components within a step. The step context. Is there a chunk context? 
I have used before the execution context while writing a Partitioner before. But those were executing in parallel.

I now need to do an ordered operation. It's basically a jdbc import job but each file needs to be committed in order else their are foreign key constraint volitions.

The simplest place I'd be able get the line count for an individual file resource is in MultiResourceItemReader before it delegates to ItemReader. But having had a look at various CompletionPolicy implementations they only seem to have access to the RepeatContext. How can I store a value in the RepeatContext from the MultiResourceItemReader so that my CompletionPolicy can access it and commit after the specific file resource line count.

An example of how to extend abstract CountingCompletionPolicy and where how to store data from MultiResourceItemReader would be helpful.

Or perhaps there is a better way to appraoch this type of job.

```
<!-- <job id="job" restartable="${restartable}" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"> -->
    <batch:job id="job" restartable="true"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <batch:step id="step1-unzipFile">
            <batch:tasklet ref="unzipFileTasklet" />
            <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="step2-import" />
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="step2-import"> <!-- we can't use a commit-interval="${commitInterval} cause it messes with 2nd pass import processing if the commit ends up being the middle of the file -->
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceReader" writer="itemWriter" chunk-completion-policy="completionPolicy"/>  
            </batch:tasklet>
            <!-- <batch:next on="COMPLETED" to="step3-fileCleanUp" /> -->
        </batch:step>
        <!-- <batch:step id="step3-fileCleanUp">
            <batch:tasklet ref="fileCleanUpTasklet" />
        </batch:step> -->
    </batch:job>




    <bean id="multiResourceReader" class="springbatch.iimport.extended.SequentialLoaderMultiFileResourceItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="resourceDirectoryPath" value="${importTempDirectoryBasePath}/#{jobParameters['jobKey']}/"/>
        <property name="delegate" ref="itemReader"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="lineMapper" ref="lineMapper" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="lineMapper" class="springbatch.iimport.extended.JsonToTupleLineMapper"/>

    <bean id="itemWriter" class="springbatch.iimport.extended.TupleJdbcBatchItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="moduleDataSource" ref="moduleDataSource"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jobKey" value="#{jobParameters['jobKey']}"/>
        <property name="jobDef" value="#{jobParameters['jobDef']}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="completionPolicy" class="?"/> 

    <!-- tasklets -->

    <bean id="unzipFileTasklet" class="springbatch.iimport.tasklets.UnZipFile" scope="step">
        <!-- the temp directory the files are unzipped to end up being #{jobParameters['importZipFileName']} -->
        <property name="importZipFileName" value="${uploadDir}/#{jobParameters['importZipFileName']}" />
        <property name="jobKey" value="#{jobParameters['jobKey']}"/>
        <property name="importTempDirectoryBasePath" value="${importTempDirectoryBasePath}" />
     </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own `CompletionPolicy` which look-ahead `itemReader` (using a `PeekableItemReader`) and return current chunk as 'completed' if next call to `itemReader.next()` returns `null` (means EOF for current file).
Remember: this solution can leads you to memory problems due to full in-memory file content reading.

```
public class EOFCompletionPolicy extends CompletionPolicySupport
{
    private EOFCompletionContext cc;
    private PeekableItemReader<Object> reader;

    public void setReader(PeekableItemReader<Object> forseeingReader)
    {
        this.reader = forseeingReader;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isComplete(RepeatContext context)
    {
        return this.cc.isComplete();
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatContext start(RepeatContext context)
    {
        this.cc = new EOFCompletionContext(context);
        return cc;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(RepeatContext context)
    {
        this.cc.update();
    }

    protected class EOFCompletionContext extends RepeatContextSupport
    {
        boolean eof = false;
        public EOFCompletionContext (RepeatContext context)
        {
            super(context);
        }

        public void update()
        {
            final Object next;
            try
            {
                next = reader.peek();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new NonTransientResourceException("Unable to peek", e);
            }
            // EOF?
            this.eof = (next == null);
        }

        public boolean isComplete() {
            return this.eof;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have a commit interval within the file. Some files might contain hundreds of thousands of lines. If I mix the SimpleCompletionPolicy functionality with EOFCompletionPolicy functionality so that it return current chunk as 'completed'  if it had either reached the chunkSize or EOF. If you could just tell me if it could work I'll figure out how to write it.

Comment: if you want (and you can manage) what you wrote in above comment you should be able to solve the problem using standard completion plicy based on commit-interval (aka chunk-sized completion policy)

Comment: I combined the boolean expressions in EOFCompletionPolicy.EOFCompletionContext.isComplete() with return (getStartedCount() >= chunkSize) || (next == null); I'm just unsure what the delegate property is in org.springframework.batch.item.support.SingleItemPeekableItemReader<T>. Can you provide a config example?

Comment: Ok I found an example here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/128731-flatfileitemreader-singleitempeekableitemreader-how-to-use-them-together (thanks for your help)

Comment: Actually the problem with this approach is next == null doesn't indicate end of individual file resource when using MultiResourceItemReader. Though maybe the the SingleItemPeekableItemReader should wrap the MultiResourceItemReader rather then it's delegate

Comment: SingleItemPeekableItemReader should use MultiResourceItemReader' delegate (`itemReader` bean in your config) as target because MultiResourceItemReader use delegate.read() to check for current resource EOF

Comment: Yeah doing that doesn't work cause MultiResourceItemReader uses the eof to decide when to move onto the next resource. A SingleItemPeekableItemReader that uses MultiResourceItemReader as a delegate will never encounter an eof indicator. So in the end I had to implement the interface and integrate logic into my own MultiResourceItemReader eg: MyMultiResourceItemReader extends AbstractItemStreamItemReader<Tuple> implements PeekableItemReader<Tuple>

Comment: That happens because my code has a bug; reader.read() should be performed into EOFCompletionContext .update() and not into EOFCompletionContext.isComplete() because `CompletionPolicy.isComplete()` is called AFTER item reading phase during chunk extraction opposite to `CompletionPolicy.update()` which is called BEFORE item reading. Try new code and let me know.